# Samsung j737p frp lock solution when OEM is also locked

Tags: samsung, frp

I have successfully flashed the eng `boot.img` via Samsung tool pro but after switching it on adb is still not active. I saw a post that claims I should load the official firmware to remove oem lock I have successfully done that but OEM is still locked. Please any solution is highly appreciated.

P.S the phone is SM-J737P refine edition.

[image]

And also all bypass solution on YouTube are not working to me.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i can think of is a method i personally discovered a few years back that has been adopted by other people and nicknamed "Pre-Hacked" ...

First you need to download a Hex Editor..

The firmware must not be encrypted...

- Open your System or Firmware file in the Hex Editor, This may take a while...
- Search for `# begin build properties`
- Once found, you have located the Build.prop start.
- Scroll through the build.prop, ( After "begin build properties" )
- Find ( ro.frp.pst=/ )
- Change the line to have a # before it ( Comment the line out )

  `ro.frp.pst=/` to `# ro.frp.pst=/`

Now you have removed FRP by breaking the crucial property that tells FRP the whereabouts of your FRP Partition.

- Save the file as a new file with the applied changes to Build.prop

Comment: thanks but a samsung firmware has various section{ AP BL CSC CP}  so which am are opening exactly?

Comment: and please can you give me a link to afree hex editor all are paid

Comment: Heres my favourite ( HxD ) ... https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/

Comment: Try all files... One of them holds the system.

Comment: thanks a lot i have search through the hex editior but i can not find the # begin build properties i can find begin. build separately but not together please help me